# Regression Model: question on conditional expectation

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, regression

Let $\{(Y_i,X_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of random pairs satisfying the model
$$Y_i=f(X_i)+u_i$$
where $E(u_i)=0$ for all $i\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$. The regression function is defined as $E(Y_i| X_i)=f(X_i)$ for all $i$.

**My question is**: without further conditions, is $E(Y_i|(X_i,X_j))=f(X_i), i\neq j,$ true? That is, the expected value of $E(Y_i|X_i)$ is changed when two observations $(X_i,X_j)$ are given? If not, when it is true?

**Comments**: I know that the sigma-algebra generated by $X_i$ is contained in $\sigma(X_i,X_j)$. So, I suspect that the conditional expectation is changed if there were some dependence structure between the observations.

Comment: You're right, it's not true in general - you need $u_i$ (or at least its mean) to be independent of $X_j$. One example of where this might fail is in a time series, where for $j > i$ the future predictor $X_j$ might depend on the past observation $Y_i$.

Comment: @Adam $E(Y_j| X_i,X_j)=E(f(X_j)+u_j| X_i,X_j)=f(X_j)+E(u_j|X_i,X_j)$. If for all $j$, $u_j$ is independent of $X_i, \forall i\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$, then $E(Y_j| X_i,X_j)=f(X_j)$ always holds. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if each $u_j$ is independent of all the $X_i$, then you can condition on them without changing the mean.

Comment: @Adam Thank you. Indeed, now I see that if $X_i$ comes out to depend on $u_j$, then $E(u_j| X_j, X_i)=E(u_j| X_j, X_i,u_j)\neq 0$.